# WCF Data encryption in WebHttpBinding

Tags: security, wcf, encryption

I have a WCF service using WebHttpBinding.
What is the best way to perform request and response data encryption?

Answer (score 0):

Services written with the WCF WEB HTTP programming model do not use SOAP messages. Because SOAP is not used, the security features provided by WCF cannot be used. You can, however use transport-based security by hosting your service with HTTPS.

For more information about WCF security, Please refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-programming-model-overview